# Como verificar variável somente com espaços em javascript?

Tags: javascript

Tenho um sistema de chat, e o botão de enviar não deve ser habilitado enquanto o usuário não digitar alguma letra.

No exemplo abaixo o botão é habilitado quando o usuário digita algo, porém se ele digitar somente espaços o botão é exibido.

```
$('#msg').on('keyup',function() {
var textarea_value = $("#msg").val();

if(textarea_value != '') {
    $('.button-enviar').attr('disabled' , false);
    $('.button-enviar').removeClass('disabled');
}else{
    $('.button-enviar').attr('disabled' , true);
    $('.button-enviar').addClass('disabled');
}
});
```

Como verificar se a variável **textarea_value** contém somente espaços? Para assim não habilitar o botão.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aproveitando o código que tem e usando [trim()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp), serve para retirar os espaços de fim/inicio de uma string:

```js
$('#msg').on('keyup',function() {
    var textarea_value = $("#msg").val().trim();
    if(textarea_value != '') {
        $('.button-enviar').attr('disabled' , false);
        $('.button-enviar').removeClass('disabled');
    }
    else{
        $('.button-enviar').attr('disabled' , true);
        $('.button-enviar').addClass('disabled');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="msg"></textarea>
<button type="button" class="button-enviar" disabled>ENVIAR</button>
```